# Custom validation script on submit for PDF - Can't get it working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, pdf, interactive

**I'm working on designing a new process for internal job submission for work which now involves javascript for it to work effectively.**

Scripting is not my forte but that hasn't deterred me, I've been able to find three different pieces of code to insert into the various buttons and fields and they've done what they should do. My problem is I need to combine some of these for an extra validation on submit. This is where I fall short.

**The process:**

1. There is a required field in the form which currently runs a custom validation script to check a certain format specific to the code needed for a job. This runs well and I was even able to add an alert and hint images that show when incorrect and a little tick when correct. Beautiful.
2. The second major part of the form is in the submit button. I hacked together a code which not only emails the submitted form with fields as the subject line but also makes all fields read only before doing so. Brilliant.

**Here's the messy part.** A user can enter a correct or incorrect required code and the validator does its bit but that doesn't stop them from still submitting the form. Fine. I can fix that by running the validator again on the submit button so it not only gives user feedback *on blur* of the required field but again validates on submit so if the field is incorrect the submit stops until the user has the correct value in the field. This is where my knowledge stops like a cliff edge and I can't seem to build a bridge.
I've tried numerous ways of calling the field value then just running the same validation script with some *if* and *else* statements but it just doesn't work.

**Can anyone help?** Current code for submission button below but keep in mind that the validation section of this code is also attached to the required field directly (this affects it?):

```
function OR_Stuff() {

      var ProjectTitle = getField("ProjectTitle").value;
      var Brand = getField("Brand").value;
      var Name = getField("Name").value;
      var Noosh = getField("INT_NooshCode").value;

      for (var i = 0 ; i < this.numFields ; i++) {
                var f = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));
                if (f.type != "Submit") // Change f.type to button name in form that the action is applied to
                          {
                                    f.readonly = true;
                          }
      }


      this.mailDoc({

      cTo: "email",

      cBcc: "email",

      cSubject: "NEW JOB: "+Brand+" - "+ProjectTitle+" - "+Noosh,

      cMsg: "Thanks "+Name+" for sending through this job."

      }); 
      }
      var re = /^\d{5}[A-Z]\d{2}$/
      if (re.test(INT_NooshCode.value) == false) {
      this.getField("RequiredAlert").display = display.visible;
      this.getField("NooshTick").display = display.hidden;
      app.alert("Sorry, we can't start a project without a Noosh code. \n\nPlease enter a valid Noosh code EG: 34256P02");

      }
      else {
      OR_Stuff();
      }
```